# Why do I always get Error while updating dependencies in Vite, on installing a new package every time?

Tags: node.js, npm, vite

Every single time I install a new package, modify my code to incorporate the features of that package as desired, and re-run the server to see the effective changes, I see this error (screenshot attached).

**Before the error, I get a message on the console saying - "Re-optimizing dependencies because lockfile has changed"**

Here's my vite.config.js file -

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    hmr: false,
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["js-big-decimal", "chunk_react"],
  },
});
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hello-pangea/dnd": "^16.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.0",
    "react-wavify": "^1.10.0",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
}
```

I have tried renaming the folder, as mentioned in the error. It doesn't work.

I usually have to delete the node_modules folder and re-install the dependencies, hoping it will work on the first attempt, or else re-do the same thing until it does.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tgzb.png)